# How to set a loop into a macro that has no integer values set?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the code below so that it will retreive the file locations and put them into Path Column(B) which corresponds to the .csv column(C) where a "YES" is found.

```
Dim csv_ap As Range
Dim path_report2 As String

Sheets("Mail Report").Activate
Set csv_ap = Range("C65000").End(xlUp)

If csv_ap.Value = "YES" Then
path_report2 = MAIN_PATH & "1. Invoices+BUFs - " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Value _
& "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Value & " - " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AK65000").End(xlUp).Value _
& "\" & "LOGGED" & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E65000").End(xlUp).Value

csv_ap.Offset(0, -1) = path_report2

End If
```

As you can see only the bottom row for column B has been filled. I'm not 100% sure why this is but could be down to not having a loop involved? I have tirelessly looked into adding a loop but cannot do so without affecting the current code. Any ideas?

[image: Mail Report.]

I have edited the code above and got a loop working. But now it is duplicating the bottom row.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim path_report2 As String

Sheets("Mail Report").Activate

For Each cell In Sheets("Mail Report").Range("C2:C10").Cells
If cell = "YES" Then
path_report2 = MAIN_PATH & "1. Invoices+BUFs - " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Value & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Value & " - " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AK65000").End(xlUp).Value & "\" & "LOGGED" & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E65000").End(xlUp).Value

cell.Offset(0, -1) = path_report2

End If
Next
```

This is the result of the macro:

[image: Result of updated macro]

Comment: Where are the file locations held? In column D and E?

Comment: I have not given enough information here I think. Basically the file loaction is built up from information in another sheet, rather than the file location itself.

Comment: Can you not simply use a `vlookup` in that case? e.g. if 'yes' then get  details from sheet X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your range is defined as a single cell by `Set csv_ap = Range("C65000").End(xlUp)`.

If you want to process all the rows from 1 to the last occupied range, then you would need:

```
Set csv_ap = Range("C1:C" & Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: Seem to be getting this message in a line of my larger macro that this small one is part of. Run Time error '92' For loop not initialized

Comment: Update your original post with more complete code and indicate exactly what line of code is highlighted when you get the error.

Comment: I have put a loop into the original code, but have now come across a new problem!

Comment: If this answered your initial question, you should mark it as such, then open a new question for your new problem. You can include a link to this one to help tie them together, but it's difficult to find an answer to a question that's buried somewhere in another one - this is the official SO procedure.